# Resultant ‘Trisecting’ the angle between the two forces

Tags: geometry, classical-mechanics

( https://i.stack.imgur.com/T76sV.jpg )
This is the Question.

The angle could have  been bisected in this case but it is **trisected**

But how?

Trisect means to divide into three equal parts but how the angle b/w the forces can be divided into 3 part by the resultant in this Case.

Comment: The smaller angle is one third of the angle between the forces.

Comment: Got it, Thank you.

Comment: @Lucifer You are right that this is completely abusing the word “trisect”.  This is more a case of “what could they have meant when they wrote this nonsensical phrase?”